# ASP.Net Application keeps prompting for cedentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

We have an MVC application hosted on IIS  6 web server. It uses integrated authentication. It's been hosted there since last 5 years. Recently our IT department had installed some patches on the server. After the patch installation, suddenly our application started prompting for credentials. When user enters his credentials, it again prompts for credentials. It keeps on repeating and user will not be able to get into the application. When user cancels the credentials window, it gives the below error:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Can somebody, please guide me to understand why it might have occurred and how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe wrong credentials?

Comment: Windows 2003 (and by extension IIS6) is out of support and has been for several years...why has the server not been upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

We actually ran into this about 8 months ago. It brought down our entire environment for 3 days. At that time we came to find that it was a Microsoft patch that was applied to our web servers in regards to NTLM authentication. I will look and see if I can find the documentation on exactly what KB it was. Our solution was (at the time) to temporarily roll back the patch. Long story short is the underlying cause turned out to be that the patch that was installed had specific dependencies on other patches being installed on the web server AND our domain controllers. I will follow up and edit my answer when I get into the office, but I recommend checking the server to see what patches got installed and take note of if any in regards to NTLM.

Try remoting into the server. Then while you are in, minimize your screen and try hitting the website again. I bet I will work and authenticate. If that is the case, then you are seeing the exact same thing we were. I will follow up in a little bit with more specifics.